# Does cron still run for disabled users?

Tags: ubuntu, user-accounts, cron

If a user is disabled (with `passwd -l user`) on a server, are their cron jobs also disabled?

Or would they still run?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They should not run.

From the manpage of [`cron(1)`](http://man.cx/cron%281%29):

> `cron` and `at` jobs will be not be executed if the user’s account is locked. Only accounts which are not locked as defined in [`shadow(4)`](http://man.cx/shadow%284%29) will have their job or process executed.